# Inserting image into BLOB column MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I Have Table Called XYZ

```
ID    no         no2           no3     

1     465         Abc       [BLOB - 15B]      
2     465         Abc       [BLOB - 18B]       
3     465         Abc       [BLOB - 80B]       
4     456         Abc       [BLOB - 50B]
```

i want to insert multiple images into "no3" using PDO

**PHP**

```
try  {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO xyz (no, no2, no3) SELECT max(nos),nos2,:tmp from ASD;
         for($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++)
        {
        $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


     $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
     $statement->bindParam(':tmp',addslashes(file_get_contents($data[$i])));
        } 
    $statement->execute();

} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
```

it insert only one image

Comment: Close the INSERT query string literal i.e. `"` at end of query

Comment: This code is not even valid and won't insert anything. Please post your *actual* code.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you're missing a closing `"`, but it seems it is there in your actual code, because the behaviour you described doesn't match this syntax error.

So, looking further, you call `execute` only after the loop.

You will have to execute the statement over and over inside the for-loop as well. 
Now you just overwrite the image in the bind parameter, call execute once, and thus only insert the last image in the database.

You should actually be able to prepare the statement once, and in the loop, for every iteration, bind a new value and execute the statement. So the code for the loop becomes this: (Assuming the details of loading the file, etc, is okay. I haven't investigated that).

```
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

for($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++)
{
    $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $statement->bindParam(':tmp',addslashes(file_get_contents($data[$i])));
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct PHP Code

```
       $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
         for($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++)
              {

              $tmp = addslashes(file_get_contents($data[$i]));
              $statement->bindParam(':tmp',$tmp);
             $statement->execute();
             }
```

Answer (score -1):

Mate you forgot to add ending " at the of the query:

```
try  {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO xyz (no, no2, no3) SELECT max(nos),nos2,:tmp from ASD";
         for($i=0; $i<=count($data)-1; $i++)
        {
        $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


     $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
     $statement->bindParam(':tmp',addslashes(file_get_contents($data[$i])));
        } 
    $statement->execute();

} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
```